# Generating nullable type properties using CodeDom

Tags: c#, properties, nullable, codedom

I'm generating some C# code using CodeDom, basically trying to replicate all the properties from an existing class. The code is fairly straightforward:

```
//type is a Type
foreach(PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
 {
    Type eType = p.PropertyType;
    AddProperty(eType, p.Name);
    // ...
 }

void AddProperty(Type propType, string name)
{
    CodeMemberProperty newProperty = new CodeMemberProperty();
    newProperty.Type = new CodeTypeReference(propType);         
    newProperty.Name = name;
    targetClass.Members.Add(newProperty);
}
```

This works well for strings, but for nullable primitive types such as `decimal?` and `int?`, in the resulting code I instead get the following:

```
public virtual System.Nullable<decimal> MyNullableDecimal
```

instead of

```
public decimal? MyNullableDecimal
```

I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the `virtual` attribute because this is added by default. In order to remove it, you have to explicitly mark it "final":

```
newProperty.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Final;
```

If you are wondering about the `T?` notation: this is merely syntactic sugar and is equal to `Nullable<T>`. I don't believe you can create it with `?` instead because you're basically working at a lower level with CodeDom.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the T? notation. Sorry about the confusion. I have guessed that it's the same thing, but I'd really like to get the T? notation into the code, as it's much neater. Could you possibly elaborate on the usage of CodeExpression for this purpose?

Comment: @Shaggydog: I looked it over again and I don't think the workaround will work since the type of a property cannot be given an expression. As far as I can tell, you're going to have to be okay with the `System.Nullable<T>` notation. The CodeDom operates at a level below what you normally work with: you have to build your code with explicit building blocks. The `?` notation is one of the many things the C# syntax provides to get a shortcut to one of the building blocks, but obviously it doesn't make much sense to intertwine this with the actual building blocks.

Comment: I see. Well, I guess it's acceptable this way. If not, I can always run some Regex on the resulting source files.